# Limiting bandwidth - Delphi 2007 ICS components

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Does anybody know how to limit/control the bandwidth of twsocket (client) in ICS components in Delphi? We have a small program that maps a port to squid. The software using ICS components that carries requests from the LAN arrives at one port to the port of squid, and returns the contents back to the originating IP. Can somebody shed some light as how to control the bandwidth to limit to certain KB/s, to keep bad boys out from using whole resources? Some code snippets may be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It is descriped in then FAQ (look for "Bandwidth control").
http://users.telenet.be/sonal.nv/ics/faq/Frame_index.html

There is also a link to a component implementing it

Comment: OK got the comp; will give it a try, thank you for pointing to right place.

Comment: The link URL returns a 404 page not found. Can you add the relevant code or information to your answer?

Comment: Try looking here: http://web.archive.org/web/20090316042742/http://www.smatters.com/ics/

Comment: But it is nativly in the newest versions of ICS (version 7 and up), look for BandwidthControl

Answer (score 0):

It seems you ar trying to simulate network constraints.
The are several comercial applications for that purpose, that also simulate latency (thats another common problem in wans).
Example of the Comercial applications are: Netlimiter, Shunra